# Prevent visual studio Query Designer to modify the query before execution

Tags: visual-studio, query-designer

MSDN says that:

> You can use the SQL pane to create your own SQL statement, or you can
>   use the Criteria pane and Diagram pane to create the statement, in
>   which case the SQL statements will be created in the SQL pane. A**s you
>   build your query, the SQL pane automatically updates and reformats to
>   be easily read**.

How to disable auto correction of my query? Is that is possible?
To keep my query in original, for example:

```
select * from table
```

to avoid converting it into

```
select field1, field2,... field100 from table
```